# Pretty Printing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

How can I print a pandas dataframe as a nice text-based table, like the following?

```
+------------+---------+-------------+
| column_one | col_two |   column_3  |
+------------+---------+-------------+
|          0 |  0.0001 | ABCD        |
|          1 |  1e-005 | ABCD        |
|          2 |  1e-006 | long string |
|          3 |  1e-007 | ABCD        |
+------------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 348):

I've just found a great tool for that need, it is called [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

It prints tabular data and works with `DataFrame`.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_two' : [0.0001, 1e-005 , 1e-006, 1e-007],
                   'column_3' : ['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'long string', 'ABCD']})

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+-----------+-------------+
|    |   col_two | column_3    |
|----+-----------+-------------|
|  0 |    0.0001 | ABCD        |
|  1 |    1e-05  | ABCD        |
|  2 |    1e-06  | long string |
|  3 |    1e-07  | ABCD        |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

Note:

> To suppress row indices for all types of data, pass `showindex="never"` or `showindex=False`.

Comment: If you do not have access to the bleeding edge, you can do  `tabulate([list(row) for row in df.values], headers=list(df.columns))` to get rid of the index

Comment: Doesn't work very well when you have hierarchies in row index and columns.

Comment: Make sure you do `print(tabulate(df, **kwargs))` and not simply `tabulate(df, **kwargs)`; the latter will show all new lines `\n`....

Comment: To suppress the left index column one may want to also add `showindex=False`

Comment: I'd really love for `pandas` to bundle `tabulate` as an optional dependency and allow `df.to_tabular(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 138):

### pandas >= 1.0

If you want an inbuilt function to dump your data into some github markdown, you now have one. Take a look at [**`to_markdown`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [1, 2, 3]}, index=['a', 'a', 'b'])  
print(df.to_markdown()) 
                                               
|    |   A |   B |
|:---|----:|----:|
| a  |   1 |   1 |
| a  |   2 |   2 |
| b  |   3 |   3 |
```

Here's what that looks like on github:

[image]

Note that `to_markdown` calls `tabulate` under the hood, so you will still need to have the [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) package installed. But this means that `to_markdown` can support 20+ different table formats via keyword arguments that it passes through to `tabulate`. As an example, you can get the same output as [Romain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885295/4909087) using `df.to_markdown(headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')`

Comment: I used the `to_markdown` to emit markdown from my script, and piped that into `glow -` ([`github`](https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow)) to render the markdown in the terminal with nice results. ([Script here](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/mint/tree/master/analyze))

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge link is either broken or unaccessible from public.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the ping; was moved to a different folder. Here's a [permalink](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/mint/blob/576f80fb9e0e0368bf96514b76c1bdb400736fdb/budget/budget/analyze/summary.py#L31-L43)

Comment: With more arguments passed to `tabulate`, `to_markdown` actually support 20 + types of format (https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate#table-format) and many other keywords.

Answer (score 70):

If you are in Jupyter notebook, you could run the following code to interactively display the dataframe in a well formatted table.

This answer builds on the to_html('temp.html') answer above, but instead of creating a file displays the well formatted table directly in the notebook:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

Credit for this code due to example at: [Show DataFrame as table in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: better than using tabulate.

Comment: For me even just `display(df)` looks good.

Comment: Marvellous, I really like it in this way. It does not only print nicely, but also shows all columns and rows... great...

Comment: Don't know why, but this gives me `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`.

Comment: from IPython.display import display; 

  display(df) works well with huge columns as well.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. But the link you shared for the credits it's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 55):

A simple approach is to output as html, which [pandas does out of the box](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html):

```
df.to_html('temp.html')
```

Comment: This is such an underrated response. No additional packages required. And in my case, I wasn't able to get tabulate to print a pivot table with two indexes the way I needed. df.to_html - no problem at all. And if you need multiple dataframes to go into the same html, just do df1.to_html() + df2.to_html() + so on...

Answer (score 16):

You can use [prettytable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) to render the table as text. The trick is to convert the data_frame to an in-memory csv file and have prettytable read it. Here's the code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import prettytable    

output = StringIO()
data_frame.to_csv(output)
output.seek(0)
pt = prettytable.from_csv(output)
print pt
```

Comment: What version of pandas was this?

Comment: AFAIK, `prettytable` is largely considered abandonware.  Shame, too, as it was a nice package. :(

Comment: @dmn so it's not maintained anymore?

Comment: `prettytable` has not had a release since Apr 6, 2013. `tabulate` is its spiritual predecessor and has regular releases, the most recent being on Jan 24, 2019.

Comment: `prettytable` has been resurrected under maintainership of jazzband! Hurray! https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable

Answer (score 16):

Following up on Mark's answer, if you're *not* using Jupyter for some reason, e.g. you want to do some quick testing on the console, you can use the `DataFrame.to_string` method, which works from -- at least -- Pandas 0.12 (2014) onwards.

```py
import pandas as pd

matrix = [(1, 23, 45), (789, 1, 23), (45, 678, 90)]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
print(df.to_string())

#  outputs:
#       a    b   c
#  0    1   23  45
#  1  789    1  23
#  2   45  678  90
```

Comment: `DataFrame.to_string` official docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_string

Comment: You don't need the `.to_string()` method if you don't process the data, `print(df)` does the same

Comment: This should be the top-rated & accepted answer. Out of the box & easy to use (and most importantly, it works!).

Comment: @Spartan Your comment only holds true if the column size is small. Otherwise "print(df)" replaces the middle columns by dots and prints the last columns again.

Comment: @Jakob: True, after all the question was about pretty printing, but you can change how much columns are shown, either globally with `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` or i.e. `with pd.option_context(‘display.max_columns’, None): print(df)`

Answer (score 8):

I used Ofer's answer for a while and found it great in most cases. Unfortunately, due to inconsistencies between [pandas's to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [prettytable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/)'s from_csv, I had to use prettytable in a different way.

One failure case is a dataframe containing commas:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': ['a,', 'b']})
```

Prettytable raises an error of the form:

```
Error: Could not determine delimiter
```

**The following function handles this case:**

```
def format_for_print(df):    
    table = PrettyTable([''] + list(df.columns))
    for row in df.itertuples():
        table.add_row(row)
    return str(table)
```

If you don't care about the index, use:

```
def format_for_print2(df):    
    table = PrettyTable(list(df.columns))
    for row in df.itertuples():
        table.add_row(row[1:])
    return str(table)
```

Comment: Hi, the `format_for_print()` function does not seem to be printing the index of the Pandas DataFrame. I set the index using `df.index.name = 'index'` but this does not print the index column with a name.

Answer (score 8):

**Maybe you're looking for something like this:**

```
def tableize(df):
    if not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        return
    df_columns = df.columns.tolist() 
    max_len_in_lst = lambda lst: len(sorted(lst, reverse=True, key=len)[0])
    align_center = lambda st, sz: "{0}{1}{0}".format(" "*(1+(sz-len(st))//2), st)[:sz] if len(st) < sz else st
    align_right = lambda st, sz: "{0}{1} ".format(" "*(sz-len(st)-1), st) if len(st) < sz else st
    max_col_len = max_len_in_lst(df_columns)
    max_val_len_for_col = dict([(col, max_len_in_lst(df.iloc[:,idx].astype('str'))) for idx, col in enumerate(df_columns)])
    col_sizes = dict([(col, 2 + max(max_val_len_for_col.get(col, 0), max_col_len)) for col in df_columns])
    build_hline = lambda row: '+'.join(['-' * col_sizes[col] for col in row]).join(['+', '+'])
    build_data = lambda row, align: "|".join([align(str(val), col_sizes[df_columns[idx]]) for idx, val in enumerate(row)]).join(['|', '|'])
    hline = build_hline(df_columns)
    out = [hline, build_data(df_columns, align_center), hline]
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        out.append(build_data(row.tolist(), align_right))
    out.append(hline)
    return "\n".join(out)


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [11111, 22, 333]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print tableize(df)
```

```
Output:
+-------+----+-----+
|    a  |  b |   c |
+-------+----+-----+
|     1 |  2 |   3 |
| 11111 | 22 | 333 |
+-------+----+-----+
```

Comment: The best answer, could you explain why it works so well tho?

Comment: This is so helpful when printing my job analytics summary tables for serverless Dataproc jobs. I didn't want to use custom containers just to add the `tabulate` library. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: This is an amazing answer! No dependencies needed for something "simple" like this, but I also don't want to code it up myself. The tables are beautiful, too.

Comment: I like this answer so much I added a max_col_width argument which should be helpful for tables with randomly long values.

Answer (score 6):

I use the [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) library for that, it has nicer looking tables than the tabulate based `.to_markdown(`).

```
import pandas as pd
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_two' : [0.0001, 1e-005 , 1e-006, 1e-007],
                   'column_3' : ['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'long string', 'ABCD']})
console = Console()
table = Table('Title')
table.add_row(df.to_string(float_format=lambda _: '{:.4f}'.format(_)))
console.print(table)
```

Gives you this table:

[image]

See the documentation for more customization options:

https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tables.html

Comment: Along the lines of this approach, there's [rich-dataframe](https://pypi.org/project/rich-dataframe/).

Comment: I just made a fork of rich-dataframe code that can be easily placed within other code **AND** where I changed it so the caption only is shown if you go over the threshold for number of rows or columns and I removed the animated aspect so it doesn't cause weird spacings if you want to use it in Jupyter. Even if you don't want quite those two customizations, seeing how I did them may help you customizing as you want. See it in my fork [here](https://github.com/fomightez/rich-dataframe/blob/master/rich_dataframe/rich_dataframe.py).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** an even better solution is to simply put the variable name of the dataframe on the last line of the cell. It will automatically print in a pretty format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': np.linspace(0,10,11), 'Data2': np.linspace(10,0,11)})
df
```

Comment: this might not be what the question is asking. leaving the variable at the end does not execute a 'print' function, i.e. the result does not persist and can easily be overwritten by another object call.