# Panda- how can I conver dataframe in to table format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is my output in Pandas from CSV file.

```
Total Schools   Total Students  Total Budget    Average Math score  Average Reading score
     15             39,170      $24,649,428        78.99                81.88
```

```
d = {'Total Schools': [school_df['name'].count()], 'Total Students': [student_df['name'].count()], 'Total Budget':[school_df['budget'].sum()], 'Average Math score':[round(student_df['math_score'].mean(),2)], 'Average Reading score':[round(student_df['reading_score'].mean(),2)]}
school_summary = pd.DataFrame(d)
school_summary = school_summary.loc[:,['Total Schools','Total Students','Total Budget','Average Math score','Average Reading score']]
school_summary['Total Budget'] = school_summary['Total Budget'].map("${:,.0f}".format)
school_summary['Total Students'] = school_summary['Total Students'].map("{:,.0f}".format)

school_summary
```

Above is my code to create dataframe. I want to convert dataframe in to table formate. Would you please suggest me code. I know there is code **school_summary.style.set_table_styles**  but I don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to save to csv and look at it in excel or openoffice

if by table format you mean a csv. then just do

`school_summary.to_csv(FILEPATH)`

where FILEPATH is where you want to save your new csv file (like `FILEPATH = r'C:\My Documents\myfile.csv'` if you're using windows os)

### If you want to pretty print in ipython

do
`from IPython.display import display`
then `display(school_summary)`

### if you want to pretty print in Python console...

the best you can do is
[Pretty Printing a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe)

(Sorry to say, but a python console is not the best way to view data.)