# python : align query result

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

how do I align all the values ​​in the middle of the query result?

```
print('\n\nThis is my first Query in Python\n')
print(tabulate(cursor, showindex=False, headers=cursor.columns))
```

this is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vask7.png)

Comment: Use the `numalign=` and/or `stralign=` named arguments to `tabulate()`. E.g. `tabulate(cursor, showindex=False, headers=cursor.columns, numalign="center")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numalign` argument, like this:

```
print('\n\nThis is my first Query in Python\n')
print(tabulate(cursor, showindex=False, headers=cursor.columns, numalign='center'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked the same question a while ago: [Pretty Printing a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe) 
I will suggest you, to take a look on the last answer and also just try in your tabulate function: `tablefmt='psql'`