# Pandas dataframe outputting as text rather than standard format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, output

I am using pandas to work with an excel file and create a dataframe from that. It's able to read the file, but when i print the resulting dataframe it's showing up in a text format which is a lot different from the normal one we are used to.

This is how i'm reading the excel file and printing it:

```
locations = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') 
print(locations)
```

this outputs as [image: bad dataframe]
which looks like a text output

I want it to output normally like this:

[image: good dataframe]

how can i fix my output?

Comment: You likely need to pass some additional parameters to `pd.read_excel()`. See the [API page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: I think you may find this to be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'pretty'format is only outputted when 'print' isn't called. Try:

```
locations = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
locations
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Jupyter notebook (which I believe you are using):

- Calling `print(dataframe)` will print results just like a python console will display, in this case like the text example you showed
- Calling `dataframe` and running a cell will print the dataframe in the prettyfied format you show in your second example

As long as you have a `DataFrame`, the format you see when printing it will not depend on the contents of the `DataFrame`, just how you actually print it