# How to read in pretty-printed dataframe into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pretty-print

```
# necessary imports
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
```

---

I have a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                   'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                   'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885295/8565438), I pretty print it:

```
prettyprint=tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')
print(prettyprint)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | A   | B   | C   | D   |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | A0  | B0  | C0  | D0  |
|  1 | A1  | B1  | C1  | D1  |
|  2 | A2  | B2  | C2  | D2  |
|  3 | A3  | B3  | C3  | D3  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

[Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214587/8565438) it to a text file:

```
with open("PrettyPrintOutput.txt","w") as text_file:
    text_file.wite(prettyprint)
```

**How can I read `PrettyPrintOutput.txt` back into a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) without doing a lot of text processing manually?**

Comment: Maybe you can look into pickling it instead of writing to a text file?

Comment: Yeah that's also good for general use. One of the main reasons I search for a solution in the above way is that I often posts on SO with dataframes given in a similar manner & find it hard to reproduce them.

Comment: IMO, the pretty printed versions of DataFrames are a nuisance (Better to just plain `print` without the decorators, or use the `to_string()` method so someone can reproduce with StringIO). For pretty print, I wind up copying them, removing the lines and then find and replacing '|' with ''. Otherwise you end up with all kinds of whitespace issues on string columns/column headers. Sure you can strip it, but it winds up being more code

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use clever keyword arguments in `pd.read_csv` / `pd.read_clipboard`:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv(r'PrettyPrintOutput.txt', sep='|', comment='+', skiprows=[2], index_col=1)
    df = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed' not in col]]
```

I just define all lines beginning with '+' as comments, so they don't get imported. This does not help against the third row, which has to be excluded using skiprow.

The second line is needed because you end up with additional columns using the '|' as separator. If you know the column names in advance use the keyword `usecols` to be explicit.

Output:

```
       A      B      C      D   
                                
0      A0     B0     C0     D0  
1      A1     B1     C1     D1  
2      A2     B2     C2     D2  
3      A3     B3     C3     D3
```

It also works with `pd.read_clipboard`, because the functions accept the same keyword arguments.

Comment: `object` columns and column headers are problematic with this approach. You'll need to strip all of them.