# Is there a way using pandas library to separate the values in adjacent columns with two spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns

I am sub setting several columns from **gapminder**  data using code:

```
df_2000 = df.loc[(df['year']>2000) & (df['country'] == 'United States') , ['year' ,'country', 'population', 'life_exp']]
```

I get the output but I need to make it more visual by separating values in different columns with 2 spaces or more so the code will be much prettier.

So for example instead of

```
Year  Country Population Life

100     AS       100000   0.6
```

I need something like

```
Year       Country     Population     Life

100          AS       100000          0.6
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Please provide more detail and example so people can help you

Comment: It seems that you want to "pretty print" your dataframe / columns. Does this SO post answers your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I need something to input myself exactly 3 spaces to separate
the values in adjacent columns.