# Specifying a delimiter when writing a DataFrame to_string

Tags: python

I want to output a DataFrame to a string while adding a delimiter for each column, but haven't found a way to do so (neither with `to_string` nor any other method). Doing it via regex, for example by substituting white spaces with the preferred delimiter, does not work since my data includes strings (sentences). Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 'This is some text', 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 'This is also some text', 5]
})

string = data.to_string(header = False)

string
```

```
'0 1 1\n1 This is some text 2 \n2 3 3\n3 4 This is also some text\n4 5 5'
```

Replacing white spaces with the preferred delimiter inserts the delimiter between every word in each sentence, which is not appropriate in this case. Is there a way to output a DataFrame to a string while specifying a delimiter for the variables?

My end goal here is to concatenate two DataFrames of different sizes (and with different variables), basically binding them row-wise, one on top of the other, and then outputting the combined results to a .csv file. The reason I am not doing this directly on the DataFrames (e.g. via `pandas.concat`) is because this forces the rows of the thus combined DataFrame to be equal (with `NaN` values for variables not included in one or the other DataFrame). This is obviously the preferred behaviour, but when printing to .csv, this produces blank spaces (e.g. `,,,` where the `NaN` values in the DataFrame would be). I need to provide a .csv file that does not include any "blanks" and thus trying to achieve it through the above method.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this is highly welcome!

Comment: as of version 1.5, pandas will have `Styler.to_string` which can do this. It exists on the master branch so you look at the code but wont have a public release for a few months,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write this as an answer ( I don't have enough reputation to comment ), but have you tried making both dataframes csv's and then concatting the files with cat, or directly writing both to the same file ( You may have to remove the header on one )

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the package `tabulate` to add delimiters. As [Pretty Printing a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe) explains,

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 'This is some text', 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 'This is also some text', 5]
})

print(tabulate(data, tablefmt='jira'))
```

produces

```
| 0 | 1                 | 1                      |
| 1 | This is some text | 2                      |
| 2 | 3                 | 3                      |
| 3 | 4                 | This is also some text |
| 4 | 5                 | 5                      |
```

There are many different formatting styles, see https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate. Pick one that suits you or make your own.