# How can I find easily which independent variable is in which factor in python?

Tags: python, factor-analysis

I found the number of factors which is 8 in Python. But I couldn't get actually which independent variable is in which factor. It would be better to see from the table. Also I couldn't see the actual values between Factor 2 and Factor 7, there is just '...' Would you please help about this issue?

Thank you so much in advance!

*fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=8,rotation='varimax')
fa.fit(df)
print(pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_,index=df.columns, columns=['Factor 1', 'Factor 2', 'Factor 3', 'Factor 4', 'Factor 5', 'Factor 6', 'Factor 7', 'Factor 8']))*

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can use `tabulate` to pretty print a Pandas DataFrame. [Check this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885295/2828341).