# How to print table in looping pyhton console

Tags: python, pandas, tabulate, lcg

I want to print a table on my console. From now am using pandas how to print using tabulate

Here is my Source code:

```
from numpy import average
import pandas as pd

z = 10119011
a = 17
c = 43
m = 499

for i in range(0, 21):
    LCG = ((a*z)+c) % m
    z = LCG
    u = z/m
    hasil = 700 + u * (1500-700+1)

    d = {
        'Random Number Integer': [z],
        'Uniform Random Number': [u],
        'Penggunaan Pertamax/hari': [hasil]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print(df)
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for > [Pretty Printing a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use tabulate, you need to pass your dataframe `df` as main argument and specify its keys:

```
from numpy import average
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

z = 10119011
a = 17
c = 43
m = 499

for i in range(0, 21):
    LCG = ((a*z)+c) % m
    z = LCG
    u = z/m
    hasil = 700 + u * (1500-700+1)

    d = {
        'Random Number Integer': [z],
        'Uniform Random Number': [u],
        'Penggunaan Pertamax/hari': [hasil]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys'))
```

**Output:**

```
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                      465                 0.931864                     1446.42
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                      463                 0.927856                     1443.21
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                      429                 0.859719                     1388.64
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                      350                 0.701403                     1261.82
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                        5                  0.01002                     708.026
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
 0                      128                 0.256513                     905.467
      Random Number Integer    Uniform Random Number    Penggunaan Pertamax/hari
--  -----------------------  -----------------------  --------------------------
.....
```