# Why is Pandas converting an existing column from int to float when running apply?

Tags: pandas

I am doing some operations on a pandas dataframe, specifically:

- Dropping a column
- Using the `dataframe.apply()` function to add a column based on an existing one

Here's the simplest test-case I've been able to create:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["Fred", 1, 44],
     ["Wilma", 0, 39],
     ["Barney", 1, None]],
    columns=["Name", "IntegerColumn", "Age" ])

def translate_age(series):
    if not np.isnan(series['Age']):    
        series["AgeText"] = "Over 40" if series["Age"] > 40 else "Under 40"
    else:
        series["AgeText"]  = "Unknown"
    return series
    
df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
print('@ before', df['IntegerColumn'].dtypes)
df = df.apply(func=translate_age, axis=1)
print('@ after', df['IntegerColumn'].dtypes)
```

The `print()` output shows the change in the **IntegerColumn**'s type. It started as an integer:

```
@ before int64
```

... and then after the `apply()` call, it changes to a float:

```
@ after float64
```

Initially, the dataframe looks like this:

```
     Name  IntegerColumn   Age
0    Fred              1  44.0
1   Wilma              0  39.0
2  Barney              1   NaN
```

... after the `apply()` call, it looks like this:

```
   IntegerColumn   Age   AgeText
0            1.0  44.0   Over 40
1            0.0  39.0  Under 40
2            1.0   NaN   Unknown
```

Why is the IntegerColumn changing from an integer to a float in this case? And how can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: I just edited to put the actual text instead of pictures. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341)

Comment: I thought it was overkill to put the pictures in the post. Can I ask what you used to get the simple text printout of the dataframe? I searched and found some solutions for prettyprinting, but they rely on extra libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: You can just use `print(df)`, that's all. Or if you want to customize the output, use `df.to_string()`. Although, I'm using VSCode Jupyter which has a "Change Presentation" option that lets you toggle plaintext and HTML when you just write `df`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was so used to the default behavior of notebooks that print out whatever the last thing you return, so I never even tried printing a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the `apply`, the rows get converted to a common dtype, i.e. float. If you didn't drop the string column, that wouldn't be possible, so the conversion wouldn't happen.

What you're doing is recommended against in [the docs for `DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> **Notes**
>
> Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported. [See Mutating with User Defined Function (UDF) methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-udf-mutation) for more details.

Instead, assign the whole column at once, for example like this:

```
def translate_age(age):
    if np.isnan(age):
        return "Unknown"
    return "Over 40" if age > 40 else "Under 40"

df['AgeText'] = df['Age'].apply(translate_age)
```