# Running function that gives strings with "\t" looks different each time

Tags: python

I have a function that will will give me the outermost value (key_n) and the inner most values, attach to a single string, and then attach it to a string that contains all the single strings combined (hopefully that makes sense).

```
big_milon = {'key_1' : {'{key1':'dasdadsad', 'key2': 'hat', 'key3':'cat'},
         'key_2' : {'key1':'fat', 'key2': 'pat','key3':'lat'}}

def string_getter():
    prop_string = ''
    full_list = ''
    for i,j in big_milon.items():
        prop_list = []
        itemcode = i
        prop = list(j.values())
        for l in range(len(prop)):
            prop_string =  prop_string +'\t'+ "{" + prop[l] + "}"
        full_list = full_list + itemcode + prop_string + '\n'
        prop_string = ''
    return full_list

print(string_getter())
```

It works fine, except that sometimes, instead of it looking like there is one tab between the values, it will look like two tabs or no tabs

e.g.

```
print(string_getter())
```

[image]

Comment: So you don't like the way tabs are printed, and we can ignore all the code? How do you want it to look? That looks correct for tabstop=4.

Comment: This is not a bug - this is expected behavior of tab (move cursor to next multiply of N). If you want consistent tabulation, use string formatting options or dedicated library, e.g. `tabulate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Printing a dictionary as a horizontal table with headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330139/python-printing-a-dictionary-as-a-horizontal-table-with-headers)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski is right, but need calculate every value size for don't reached initial offset value.

Answer (score 3):

`\t` is not for spacing, it's meant for tabulating. `\t` (or `tabulation`), by default, skips to the next next column multiple of 8... (+ 1 in reality, as we start counting at 1). So, if you're in columns 1-8, a `\t` will skip to column 9. If you're in 9-16, it'll skip to 17, etc.

At least, that's the old signification - from mechanical typewriters and teletypes. (even there is some leeway: Some mechanical typewriters allowed settings of the tab columns)

[image: The dots are spaces, the arrows are the result of tab characters, tabs size set to 8]*The dots are spaces, the arrows are the result of tab characters, tabs size set to 8*

Modern computers and editor permit redefinition of the the tab size - generally in Preferences. Frequently they also permits automatically change tabs (`\t`) into spaces, and the other way around.

Generally, this has made the use of tabs into a nightmare. You can write a text using tabs (eg a program), but if you send it to someone, most like he/she will see the text differently. Here are some examples of 'words' separated by tabs and different settings:

[image: Tab size set to 8]*Tab size set to 8*

[image: Tab size set to 2]*Tab size set to 2*

[image: Tab size set to 4]*Tab size set to 4*

Exception to this is the [use of `\t` as a data separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) (more or less like you are doing). There's still some measure of order in the output, unless some of the words are longer that 8 characters.

On the other hand, languages like Python, which depend on spacings to format code, suffer particularly from this and [recommend not changing the tab size from 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id18). And Python 3 apparently even disallows mixing tabs and spaces to avoid more confusion.

To making things even worse, tabs in some contexts have other meanings: like in stackoverflow.com, where tabs change 'area'. If I press tab now, I'll land in other part of the screen. [Here](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tabs-used-right/) are some usage guidelines for tabs in computer use.